# strftime('%m',date) returns wrong month value only for 2 months

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room, mpandroidchart

I've been looking up a few anwers around but I'm still confused about this problem.

I'm using Room and I have a database in which I store dates with the following format:
'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.sss', since I create them using `LocalDateTime.now()`.

I'm trying to perform a query to get the items which date are between start_date and end_date, both with format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I'm getting the values from a DatePickerDialog, so no time attached.

I tried these 2 queries, both giving me wrong results:

```
@Query("SELECT strftime('%m-%Y',date) as month, COUNT(*) as total from items 
WHERE date>= :start_date AND date< :end_date GROUP BY strftime('%m-%Y',date)")

LiveData<List<Result>> getResult(String start_date, String end_date);
```

```
@Query("SELECT strftime('%m',date) as month, COUNT(*) as total from items 
WHERE date>= :start_date AND date< :end_date GROUP BY strftime('%m',date)")

LiveData<List<Result>> getResult(String start_date, String end_date);
```

Now I get the month number correctly with both queries ("02" or "02-2020", for example), but not the total count. The issue is it still doesn't count the items which item_date=end_date. Changing the query part from `AND date< :end_date` to `AND date<= :end_date` doesn't work, and I want to make sure it counts all records of start and end month, regardless of the time stamp.

I want to count the number of items of each month within the dates selected. For simplicity, I only let the user to select dates within the last year (for example, from July to June). The 2 values I want to get are the number of the month (1-12) and the total of items of that month.

How can I get any of this query to work?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1: I solved part of the issue, my mistake was that I was using a POJO with wrong data type (I was using an int to get the strftime("%m-%Y", date) part). It was solved by changing it to this:

```
public class Tuple{

    @ColumnInfo(name="month")
    private String Date; // my mistake was here, had int instead of String
....

}
```

EDIT2: The post was long, so I'm editing to only leave the relevant information plus what worked for me, in case it helps others: I used the suggested tip of the accepted answer (wrapping dates with `date()`) and changing the end date limit part to `AND date<= :end_date` again.

Comment: Suggest you use [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) to debug the problem. You might be able to [use it remotely over adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sqlite3) or can use the Android Studio Device File Explorer to copy your database onto your development system and run sqlite3 on the copy.

I tried to reproduce the problem using the info in your post and was not able to get your results.  Is your `items` table small enough that you could edit your post to include the output of `SELECT date FROM items` so we could see exactly what the `date` values in your DB are?

Comment: @BobSnyder Thank you for the fast response. Thanks to your suggestion I saw my problem was at getting the date field with a POJO using the wrong data type, now my issue is only at getting the total count, I just edited the question.

Comment: Can you post the class representation of your table of also?

Comment: @VivekSasidharan Sure, added right after the queries. Getters and setters were autogenerated, so let me now if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlite doesn't have `DateTime` data type. So your storing date as strings. Your also filtering in your query using `Date` strings (by comparing to `DateTime` string). For the queries date arguments, you are using `YYYY-MM-DD` format while for storage your using `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. This is a string comparison and such an inconsistent comparison may yield unexpected results.

I would recommend:

1. You use `date()` in sqlite to follow a consistent date format to compare the date strings.

Or better

2. Use [`TypeConverter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter) in `Room`and store dates in a format like `long` and use that for comparison.

Comment: It works finally, wrapping the date with ```date()```  and changing the query back to ```AND date<= :end_date```  adding the ```=``` did the trick. In this case I can't get rid of the time stamp because I need it for other purposes so this came in handy, thank you!